# How to merge the time data in 24 hour format in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame as following:

```
v2        v3
10:37:38  adakjl
10:38:02  sdjfisaofj
11:11:57  asdhad
12:42:02  asjla
```

I'd like to extract another data frame, which merge the rows whose time values are in a same hour and counts the number of entries like that:

```
v2                  v3
10:00:00-11:00:00   2
11:00:00-12:00:00   1
12:00:00-13:00:00   1
....
```

I wonder how to do it? I have searched the zoo documents but just found the methods of merging data in the same year or quarterly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="v2        v3
10:37:38  adakjl
10:38:02  sdjfisaofj
11:11:57  asdhad
12:42:02  asjla")
tab <- as.data.frame(table(strptime(df$v2, "%H:%M:%S")$hour), stringsAsFactors = F)
tab[, 1] <- sprintf("%02d:00:00-%02d:00:00", as.integer(tab[, 1]), as.integer(tab[, 1])+1)
tab
#                Var1 Freq
# 1 10:00:00-11:00:00    2
# 2 11:00:00-12:00:00    1
# 3 12:00:00-13:00:00    1
```

Comment: Thanks, your method works. But how to plot the histograms now? Seems that only point scatter is accessible in ggplot when both x and y are set.

Comment: my code is `ggplot(time, aes(x = time$Var1, y = time$Freq)) + geom_histogram(colour = "blue")` and get an error `stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic.`

Comment: Mine is `ggplot(tab, aes(Var1, Freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")` - works fine.

Comment: Hi luke, you have answered me several questions and your answers are always of great help. Now I am stuck by another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973314/visualize-a-social-network-to-show-how-often-a-user-is-mentioned-in-r?noredirect=1#comment57676387_34973314 and no one can give an answer. Could you please help me for this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite straightforward using **dplyr**.

```
## sample data
dat <- data.frame(time = c("10:37:38", "10:38:02", "11:11:57", "12:42:02"), 
                  value = c("adakjl", "sdjfisaofj", "asdhad", "asjla"))

## count hourly observations
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(time = substr(time, 1, 2)) %>%
  count(time) %>%
  mutate(time = as.integer(time), 
         time = paste0(time, ":00:00-", time+1, ":00:00"))
```

And here is the consle output.

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

               time     n
              (chr) (int)
1 10:00:00-11:00:00     2
2 11:00:00-12:00:00     1
3 12:00:00-13:00:00     1
```

Comment: Instead of the double mutate, you could add more pipes: `dat %>% mutate(time = substr(time, 1, 2)) %>% count(time) %>% mutate(time = time %>% as.integer %>% paste0(":00:00-",.+1,":00:00"))`

Comment: Thanks for reply! But got an error: `Error: invalid subscript type 'integer'`. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the complete dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the zoo package.

**1)** Create a function, `toInveral` which given a time produces the corresponding time interval.  Then have zoo read it in using that function to convert `v2` and using `aggregate = length` to perform the count.  Omit the `fortify.zoo` statement if you prefer to leave it as a zoo object.

```
library(zoo)

toInterval <- function(x) {
  hr <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%H:%M:%S")
  h00 <- "%H:00:00"
  paste(format(hr, h00), format(hr + 3600, h00), sep = "-")
}
z <- read.zoo(DF, header = TRUE, FUN = toInterval, aggregate = length)
fortify.zoo(z)

giving:

              Index z
1 10:00:00-11:00:00 2
2 11:00:00-12:00:00 1
3 12:00:00-13:00:00 1
```

**2)** Here is a variation that might be preferable if you want to manipulate it later.  It makes use of the `"times"` class in chron like this (or omit the `+ 1/24` to use the starting rather than ending time):

```
library(chron)
toHour <- function(x) trunc(times(x), "hour") + 1/24
z2 <- read.zoo(DF, header = TRUE, FUN = toHour, aggregate = length)
fortify.zoo(z2)
```

giving:

```
     Index z2
1 11:00:00  2
2 12:00:00  1
3 13:00:00  1
```

**Note:** We used this data.frame as input:

```
Lines <- "v2        v3
10:37:38  adakjl
10:38:02  sdjfisaofj
11:11:57  asdhad
12:42:02  asjla"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```