# Visualize a social network to show how often a user is mentioned in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, social-networking

Given a data frame as following:

```
v1    v2  v3     v4   v5
tom   A    pinky  A   3
ben   B    hugo   C   2
lily  A    tom    A   1
...
```

Which denotes that `v1` from group `v2` has mentioned `v3` from group `v4` for `v5` times. For instance, tom from group A has mentioned pinky from group A for 3 times. Now I'd like to plot a social network, each user denoted by a point and its size is proportional to the times he or she has been mentioned totally. And there is a line linkage two points if they have mentioned each other mutually or unilaterally.

As I look into the ggplot document, I can not find any function to do it.

Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is the graph I get so far:
[image]

Comment: Please add what you've tried and where you're stuck. As the question stands right now, it looks like a tool request and is in danger of being closed as such.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I wonder how to do it. As I look into the ggplot document, I can not find any function to do it.

Comment: I think you will need to use the igraph package for those kind of analyses and plots. Check here: http://igraph.org/r/ and here: http://michael.hahsler.net/SMU/LearnROnYourOwn/code/igraph.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

# create example dataset
dt = data.frame(v1 = c("tom", "ben", "lilly", "mark"),
                v2 = c("A","B","A","C"),
                v3 = c("pinky", "hugo", "tom", "pinky"),
                v4 = c("A","D","A","A"),
                v5 = c(20,10,15,15),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

dt

#      v1 v2    v3 v4 v5
# 1   tom  A pinky  A 20
# 2   ben  B  hugo  D 10
# 3 lilly  A   tom  A 15
# 4  mark  C pinky  A 15


# select columns of names to use for the graph
dt_graph = dt %>% select(v1,v3)

# create the graph
g = graph.data.frame(dt_graph)

# count number of times names were mentioned
dt_times_mentioned =
  dt %>%
  group_by(v3) %>%
  summarise(times = sum(v5))

dt_times_mentioned

#      v3 times
#   (chr) (dbl)
# 1  hugo    10
# 2 pinky    35
# 3   tom    15


# join back to the vertex names to include names in the graph that were not mentioned
dt_weights =
  data.frame(names = names(V(g)), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  left_join(dt_times_mentioned, by=c("names"="v3")) %>%
  mutate(times = ifelse(is.na(times), 0, times))

dt_weights

#   names times
# 1   tom    15
# 2   ben     0
# 3 lilly     0
# 4  mark     0
# 5 pinky    35
# 6  hugo    10


# create two datasets based on 1st and 2nd column of names
dt1 = dt %>% select(names=v1, group=v2) 
dt2 = dt %>% select(names=v3, group=v4)


# get distinct names and their group values
dt_group = 
  dt1 %>% rbind(dt2) %>% distinct() %>% 
  mutate(color = colors()[as.numeric(factor(group))+5]) # get colours from group values

#(note that the +5 above is an arbitrary value for this example in order to get colors easy to distinguish. this is not really needed. if you don't have many groups you can manually set the colors)

dt_group

#   names group         color
# 1   tom     A antiquewhite3
# 2   ben     B antiquewhite4
# 3 lilly     A antiquewhite3
# 4  mark     C    aquamarine
# 5 pinky     A antiquewhite3
# 6  hugo     D   aquamarine1


# plot the graph
plot(g, vertex.size = dt_weights$times, vertex.color = dt_group$color)

# add legend
legend(1.5, 1.5,
       legend=unique(dt_group$group),
       pch=19,
       col=unique(dt_group$color),
       title = "Colors - Groups")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply! Seems that it really works. But just one another little question, can I make it looks better? As I need to show it to others, Thanks!

Comment: An easy option is to use `tkplot(g, vertex.size = dt_weights$times)` in the end and try to experiment with all the options it gives you. Eg. Drag names to different positions, change size, colour, etc.

Comment: Sorry that I did not give full information so there are some problems when using your code, now I have edited the question. Actually, there are tag column behind the names and I want them to decide the colour of points. When I use your code, the tag value are also recorded as names. Could you please tell how to deal with it in this new situation. Apologize for my stupid mistakes again!

Comment: In this example tom has 2 tags (A and B from columns v2 and v4). Each name should have one tag/group/colour, right?

Comment: I have added the result at present in my question.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I show the legend in the graph?

Comment: What kind of legend do you want to add?

Comment: To indicate which group correspond to which color

Comment: It is possible, but if you have many groups (and many colors) it might be too much for a plot. I'll add an example based on the small dataset I have here.

Comment: Yes it works! But what if the dt_group$color is a continuous value? (Sorry I am quite new to R and igraph)

Comment: In this case it should have color values, because it needs to be used in `plot(g, vertex.size = dt_weights$times, vertex.color = dt_group$color)`. If it has any other values, you have to find a way/process to transform it to color values. If you have a specific example in mind let me know.

Comment: Indeed I have already asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994503/mapping-a-specific-column-of-values-to-the-scale-color-of-vertexs-in-r

Comment: And you can regard the a,b,c,d in that question as names of people.