# Mapping a specific column of values to the scale color of vertexs in R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

Now I have a data frame `df1`:

```
v1                v2
a                 10
b                 1
c                 3
d                 7
.......
```

And another data frame `df2`:

```
v1                v2
d                 a
c                 a
b                 c
c                 d
...
```

I'd like to plot a network based on `df2` with `igraph`:

```
plot(g, layout = layout_in_circle(g))
```

And the color of vertexes(`a,b,c,d...`) should be in range of red to blue and the bigger the value in v2, the color of that vertex should be more closer to red. 
I have tried:

```
require(igraph)
g = graph.data.frame(df)
plot(g, layout = layout_in_circle(g), vertex.color = color.scale(mention_counted$V2,c(0,1,1),c(1,1,0),0))
```

But the color of vertexes is not map to the value in v2 properly.
Is there a way to do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: A good way to map a set of numeric values to a set of colors is `colorRampPalette`.

Comment: @AntoniosK But R can automatically know it is the value for that vertex?

Comment: You have to pass the colors in the right order, so you have to see the order of the vertices in your graph object. I'll post an example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

# data frame to get colours
dt1 = data.frame(v1 = c("a","b","c","d"),
                 v2 = c(10, 1, 3, 7))

dt1

#   v1 v2
# 1  a 10
# 2  b  1
# 3  c  3
# 4  d  7


# create color column
dt1$color = colorRampPalette(c("blue","red"))(max(dt1$v2))[dt1$v2]

dt1

#   v1 v2   color
# 1  a 10 #FF0000
# 2  b  1 #0000FF
# 3  c  3 #3800C6
# 4  d  7 #AA0055


# data frame to get network
dt2 = data.frame(v1 = c("d","c","b","c"),
                 v2 = c("a","a","c","d"))

dt2

#   v1 v2
# 1  d  a
# 2  c  a
# 3  b  c
# 4  c  d


# build graph
g = graph.data.frame(dt2)

# check order of vertices
V(g)

# + 4/4 vertices, named:
#   [1] d c b a


# get info for vertices in the right order
dt_info =
  data.frame(names = names(V(g))) %>%
  inner_join(dt1, by = c("names"="v1"))

dt_info

#   names v2   color
# 1     d  7 #AA0055
# 2     c  3 #3800C6
# 3     b  1 #0000FF
# 4     a 10 #FF0000

# plot graph
plot(g, vertex.color = dt_info$color)
```

Comment: when I tried to add the column `dt$color`, an error occurs: `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "color", value = c("#1200EC", "#AD0051",  : 
  replacement has 25 rows, data has 39` Why?

Comment: Probably in `dt` you have some of the vertices names in multiple rows. The number of colors should be equal to the number of unique vertices you have in your graph.

Comment: You mean the value in dt$V2? Yes the value must have duplicate. How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: I mean `dt$v1` (the a,b,c,...) they should have only 1 row each with their name (`v1`) and the number which will give us the color (`v2`). No reason to have multiple rows, because this would mean they should have 2 colors!

Comment: Maybe I am not clear enough, I am failed at this line of code: `dt1$color = colorRampPalette(c("blue","red"))(max(dt1$v2))[dt1$v2]`

Comment: `replacement has 25 rows, data has 39` this means you're trying to create a column with 25 values to a dataset that has 39 rows. You should check why this happens.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but here you use the value of `dt1$v2` to create `dt1$color`, right?

Comment: Yes. Just make sure you have a clean workspace and try to run it again. It should work. Above you mentioned `dt$color` and not `dt1$color`.

Comment: Now the new question is what if the order of `dt1` and `dt2` is different? How can I set them properly

Comment: The best way to get answers to your questions here to create a process that this will be a problem so people can work on it. So, create an example where a different order causes you a problem and people can work it out.

Comment: The answer is similar to your previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973314/visualize-a-social-network-to-show-how-often-a-user-is-mentioned-in-r/34975391?noredirect=1#comment57719426_34975391, when you get the right order from `V(g)` and you join the rest of the info you want so you can have always the right order. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I met the same problem again:`Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "color", value = c("#FF0000", "#12EC00",  : 
  replacement has 40 rows, data has 54` I thought it is bacause of the zero value. As there are totally 14 `0` in V2 of my data frame

Comment: The problem is solved now. But another one is the order of color is still wrong. The result of `str(g)` is `[1] A-> C  D ->E ..` But the order of `dt_ info` is A  D  C E Maybe you should expand the data to 8 value in a column so that you can see the problem.

Comment: I have to use the same datasets as you, otherwise it's difficult to create this issue. `str(g)` shows the connections and not the vertices. The correct order is what you get when you type `V(g)`.

Comment: Yes it really works finally. Thank you soooooooooooooooooooooooo much. You are amazing.